# Use .map to turn quantity into percentages

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'd like to use Javascript's lodash to turn this object of arrays into percentages.  Here is the object:

```
gender = { 
  female: [14, 33, 28, 49],
  male: [33, 50, 42, 61]
}
```

I would like the above object to be

```
genderPercent = { 
  female: [0.2978, 0.3975, ..., ...],
  male: [0.7021, 0.6024, ..., ...]
}
```

Here is what I already tried:

```
_.map(gender, function (val, index, list) {
  gender["male"][gender["male"].length-1] / gender["male"][gender["male"].length-1] + gender["female"][gender["female"].length-1])
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions? :)

(Note: I need the solution to scale with time because my gender array(s) continue to grow each month.)

Comment: What kind of stat are you trying to get? Your logic doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a for loop if the male and female lengths will always be the same:

```js
var gender = { 
  female: [14, 33, 28, 49],
  male: [33, 50, 42, 61]
}
var m = gender.male;
var f = gender.female;

var genderP = {female:[], male:[]};
for (var i = 0; i < gender.female.length; i++) {
  var t = m[i] + f[i];
  genderP.male.push(m[i]/t);
  genderP.female.push(f[i]/t);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(genderP, null, 2));
/*
{
  "female": [
    0.2978723404255319,
    0.39759036144578314,
    0.4,
    0.44545454545454544
  ],
  "male": [
    0.7021276595744681,
    0.6024096385542169,
    0.6,
    0.5545454545454546
  ]
}
*/
```

`_.zip` and `_.unzip` can also be used:

```js
var gender = { 
  female: [14, 33, 28, 49],
  male: [33, 50, 42, 61]
}

var genderP = _.zipObject(['male', 'female'], _.chain(_.zip(gender.male, gender.female))
  .map(function(pair) {
    var t = pair[0] + pair[1]
    return [pair[0] / t, pair[1] / t]
  })
  .unzip()
  .value());

console.log(JSON.stringify(genderP, null, 2));
/*
{
  "male": [
    0.7021276595744681,
    0.6024096385542169,
    0.6,
    0.5545454545454546
  ],
  "female": [
    0.2978723404255319,
    0.39759036144578314,
    0.4,
    0.44545454545454544
  ]
}
*/
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just a `for` loop?

```
var genderPercent = { male: [], female: [] );
for (var i=0; i<gender.male.length && i<gender.female.length; i++)
{
    malePercent = gender.male[i] / (gender.male[i] + gender.female[i]);
    genderPercent.male.push(malePercent);
    genderPercent.female.push(1 - malePercent);
}
```

EDIT: Just saw your note. This solution will not do that, but I think it's impossible to do it in less than linear time. You must do the calculation for each one.

EDIT 2: Actually linear time is pretty scalable; I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

How does this strike you? I think it does what you wanted.

```
var genders = { 
  female: [14, 33, 28, 49],
  male: [33, 50, 42, 61]
};

var percents = _.map(genders, function(gender_val, gender) {
  return _.map(gender_val, function(val, i) {
    var opposite = gender == "male" ? "female" : "male";
    return val / (val + genders[opposite][i]);
  });
});
var genderPercents = _.zipObject(_.keys(genders), percents);
console.log(genderPercents);
```

Outputs the following:

```
Object {female: Array[4], male: Array[4]}
  female: Array[4]
    0: 0.2978723404255319
    1: 0.39759036144578314
    2: 0.4
    3: 0.44545454545454544
  male: Array[4]
    0: 0.7021276595744681
    1: 0.6024096385542169
    2: 0.6
    3: 0.5545454545454546
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an array comprehension (in this case native, not underscore), you can do it like this:

```
var gender = { 
  female: [14, 33, 28, 49],
  male: [33, 50, 42, 61]
};

var genderPercent = gender.female.reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
    var f = p.female[i];
    var m = p.male[i];
    var sum = f+m;
    p.female[i] = f/sum;
    p.male[i] = m/sum;
    return p;
}, gender);
```

This will fail if the female and male lists are of different lengths.

Additionally, it's not going to scale nearly as well as preserving the result each month and appending the new percentages, rather than recalculating all of them each time.